# How to create a Navigation Controller View like the one used when we make calls on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am looking for a view that looks like the one when we make a call on the iPhone, which looks to be a custom naivagation controller.. I could nt find an appropriate name for it but i m sure it was already answered..

Answer (score 0):

There is no Apple-supplied view like this.  You would need to create your own.

Comment: i know that :).. is it created by some one else already ? that's what i wanted to know..